# Пауза консоли в C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, консоль

Какие функции в Visual Studio (помимо `system("pause");`) останавливают закрытие консоли.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73746/discussion-on-question-by-naggan----c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если речь идет только о работе в IDE, для приостановки работы программы можно использовать обычные точки останова и отладчик, какие-то специальные вызовы в коде не нужны. Более того, использование вызовов типа *system("pause")* приведет к тому, что программу невозможно будет нормально вызывать из пакетных файлов: она будет каждый раз ждать ввода с реальной консоли, даже если стандартный ввод перенаправлен из файла и ожидалась работа без участия пользователя. Но, если все же **действительно** нужно приостановить консоль при любом запуске программы, есть несколько вариантов:

```
system("PAUSE");
```

Особенности:

- Отображает приглашение ввода ("Нажмите любую клавишу")
- Прерывает работу программы до нажатия любой клавиши
- Работает только под Windows (в других ОС нет команды PAUSE)
- Внутренне вызывает командный интерпретатор, поэтому считается "тяжелым" вариантом (если производительность что-то значит в данном случае)

Есть миф, что такой вызов небезопасен, так как если поместить в папку с программой вредоносный файл pause.exe, он будет вызван вместо команды PAUSE. Это не так в современных версиях Windows.

```
system("PAUSE>nul");
```

То же самое, но не отображает приглашение ввода.

```
getchar(); //С
cin.get(); //C++
```

Особенности:

- Не отображает приглашение ввода
- Прерывает работу программы до нажатия клавиши Enter
- Стандартная функция - работает в любом окружении

В отличие от других вариантов, не ломает перенаправление стандартного ввода (достаточно поместить на вход строку любого содержания, и выполнение программы пойдет дальше).

```
#include <conio.h>
getch(); //Традиционная
_getch(); //Современный вариант
```

Особенности:

- Не отображает приглашение ввода
- Прерывает работу программы до нажатия любой клавиши
- Нестандартная функция, доступна в DOS и Windows (в других ОС есть похожие аналоги)

Опять же, существует миф, что в Windows это какой-то DOSовский вызов и использовать его - дикий криминал. На самом деле, внутренне он реализуется как обычный вызов WINAPI-функции *ReadConsoleInput*, с предварительным отключением у консоли режима *ENABLE_LINE_INPUT*. Убедиться в этом можно, заглянув в исходники отладочной версии CRT, которые с некоторого времени частично открыты.